# Find the number of 0,1 sequence with length 2m

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, catalan-numbers

Suppose a sequence {$a_n$} with $2m$ terms, including $m$ terms equal to $1$ and m terms equal to $0$.

Such a sequence is defined as **normal** if

> For arbitrary $k \leq 2m$, the number of terms equal to $0$ is not less than that of terms equal to $1$ in the first $k$ terms {$a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_k$}.

Otherwise, it is **ab**normal.

Show that the number of abnormal $0-1$ sequences {$a_n$} with $2m$ terms equals **that of** sequences {$a_n$} of which $(m + 1)$ terms are $0$s and $(m − 1)$ terms are $1$s.

---

Below is my thought:

This problem is equivalent to prove $C_{2m}^m - \textbf{number of normal sequences} = C_{2m}^{m-1}$. The total cases of $2m$ sequences with $m$ ones and $m$ zeros minus normal cases should be the number of abnormal cases.

So I tried to find normal cases. I am considering a sequence like $\{0,1,0,1,...,0,1\}$. If I exchange the position of a ${1,0}$ pair, this sequence is still normal. But I failed to go any further. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Am I misreading the question? It seems to me it should be trying to show $A=B$ where $A \equiv C_{2m}^m - \text{number of normal sequences with $m$ zeros and $m$ ones},~~~$
    while
$~~~B \equiv C_{2m}^{m-1} - \text{number of normal sequences with $m+1$ zerosa and $m-1$ ones}$